# Bind to DependencyProperty of Window

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to create a CheckBox for toggling the Topmost property of the window.

If TopMost was a property of the ViewModel, I'd use this:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Topmost}">Topmost</CheckBox>
```

But `Topmost` is a DependencyProperty on the `Window` in which the `CheckBox` is situated.
I tried the following:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Topmost, Source={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">Topmost</CheckBox>
```

but I get the following error at runtime:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Topmost' property not found on 'object' ''RelativeSource' (HashCode=12083439)'. BindingExpression:Path=Topmost; DataItem='RelativeSource' (HashCode=12083439); target element is 'CheckBox' (Name=''); target property is 'IsChecked' (type 'Nullable`1')
```

What's my mistake here?

I could give the window an `x:Name="MyWindow"` and then use

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Topmost, ElementName=MyWindow}">Topmost</CheckBox>
```

instead, but I'd prefer to avoid `x:Name` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `RelativeSource` property of the Binding instead of the `Source` property:

```
<CheckBox Content="Topmost"
          IsChecked="{Binding Topmost,
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
```

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks. *sigh* I can never seem to get relative bindings right.

Comment: You're welcome. You can also write them less verbose :-)